# Java Logging Explanation

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, logging, jetty

This is something I have never really fully understood, I wonder if anyone can explain it?

I have a spring application, using hibernate. I sometimes run it on tomcat, sometimes on jetty. I get log output from hibernate and spring fine. I understand that there are several choices when it comes to java logging eg java.logging, slf4j, log4j, etc; but have not really got involved in configuring logging at all. Now that i want to configure ehcache's log output i need to!

My question is, in my application, how can i tell what kind of logging it is using, and how to configure and fine tune it? Does it depend on the app server? Or is it spring or hibernate that has pulled in its own logging implementation. Looking through my maven dependency tree i can see that hibernate-validator pulls in org.jboss.logging, and that spring has required commons-logging. I also have slf4j, because several packages required differing versions of it so i pulled in the latest one manually.

### Maven dependencies are:

```
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.10.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:jar:3.6.10.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] +- com.vividsolutions:jts:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernatespatial:hibernate-spatial-postgis:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernatespatial:hibernate-spatial:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.1-901-1.jdbc4:compile
[INFO] +- org.postgis:postgis-jdbc:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.postgis:postgis-stubs:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-instrument:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-instrument-tomcat:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-aspects:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.CR2:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator-annotation-processor:jar:4.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- javaxt:javaxt-core:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] +- org.glassfish:javax.servlet:jar:3.0:test
[INFO] +- javax:javaee-web-api:jar:6.0:provided
[INFO] \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.1.GA:compile
```

Cheers,
NVF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My question is, in my application, how can i tell what kind of logging it is using, and how to configure and fine tune it?**

First of all you should notice that commons logging is no logging framework, it is just a bridge/Facade between different logging frameworks. So if one framework use commons logging, then you can "configure" commons logging to forward the logging statements to an real logging framework (log4j, slf4j, java logging...)

Second you should know, that if one framework (spring, hibernate, ...) using loggingframework X than you can not mutch about it. You need to provide that logging framework. But there is one trick.

Slf4j provides a trick to "replace" other frameworks, assume:

- you have framework X, that uses for example Log4j
- but you do not ship log4j with your application, but an other library that implements the bridge Pattern (it has the same interface (Interfaces and Classes) like Log4j but internally it forwards the logging statements to slf4j. (For example: log4j-over-slf4j)

With this trick you can have unify all logging statements from different frameworks that are implemented to use different loggingframeworks to one logging framework.

BTW: you should know that Slf4j itself it is only a Facade/Bridge like commons logging:
- you can forward the logging statements to an special logging framework you want
- or to the native implementation logback

I strongly recommend to read the [slf4j manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) and [Bridging legacy APIs](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html)

**Does it depend on the app server?**
I can only speak for Tomcat (you mentioned it): Tomcat provides no Logging Framework for you application by default.

BTW: Tomcat is a Servletcontainer, no application Server.

---

According to [Ehcache Documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/operations/logging)  (First Hit when google for "Ehcache logging"), it uses slf4j.

Comment: Thats great, thanks. seems as though ehcache-core depends on commons-logging and slf4j so ill check them both out first.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't as simple as you think, listing maven dependencies alone isn't enough. You have to open your class source code and see what Logger it uses.

As an example following class uses slf4j:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Foo {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);

  public void sayHello() {
    logger.debug("hello");
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

But to make it more complicated, slf4j is a generalized logging framework which can be plugged with log4j, java commons logging etc.

So yes you can have different class within **the same application** uses different loggin framework. Also you can have your webapp container uses different logging framework than your webapp.

Answer (score -1):

You can find the logging framework, by running a debugger ;)
This is an answer that solves problem.